Whats the benifit of t min chess game?
How many openings are there? Isn't it enough to play 1 min bullet games? What's the brain development use of playing 10 or 30 min chess games. By what factor does it help as in 10^n .
In general if we play a t min chess game whats the benifit of two thousand rated players playing against each other?

Please take the time to visit the help Center (https://chess.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what this site is about. In particular what types of questions are allowed and which are not allowed. There is a limit of one question per post.
